# Print autor-name of record

Tags: bolt-cms

On my Bolt 2.0 webpage I have a News-Content type. Now I would like to show the name/alias of the autor of the record on the page.  I have tried to use {{user.username}}, but this gives me the actual user and not the one that created the record. What field do I have to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 {{record.user.displayname}}
```